# Perl threads stop working suddenly after long runs

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a perl script, that goes through a queue of files and process files in different threads:

Below is a snippet after filling the files queue.
The problem is, sometimes when I leave it running for too long (12-24 hours), I come back to see the script hanging.

I have log files for each thread, I see that the last time stamp of activity is always the same for all of them. But the script does not exit, meaning that the threads do not give back the semaphore.
Also I am sure that the threads did not end properly, because I can still see the queue is full of files to be handled.

I have a log before and after calling the EXE, and the last trace is always the one after calling the EXE. Cannot find a rational explanation.

```
#initiate all threads
for( my $i = 0; $i < $max_thread; $i++ )
{
   my $my_thread = threads->new( sub { start() } );
   push( @Threads, $my_thread );
}

$semaphore->down($max_thread);

terminate();    
sub start
{
   $SIG{INT} = sub { thread_exit() };

   while( (my $file = $file_queue->dequeue_nb) )
   {
      #This function calls an external EXE
      processFile( $file );
   }

    #Thread ended
    $semaphore->up();

}
```

Comment: Neither can we without knowing what's going on in `processFile`. Could be the thread abnormally terminating and thus not releasing the semaphore. .

Comment: Also: why `dequeue_nb`? why not just `dequeue` and `end` the queue when you're done with processing. Also - `new ( sub { start() } )` - why do you need an anonymous sub to call another sub. Is `thread -> create ( \&start)` not actually sufficient  for some reason?

Comment: Can't really tell why you're using semaphores here at all. I mean, what's wrong with waiting for a `join` operation?

Answer (score 0):

If an uncaught exception is thrown in your thread, the semaphore will never be "upped". It looks like you are using the semaphore to wait for the thread to exit, which can be done more safely using `$thread->join`.

That's assuming you are correct about the thread having exited. It could also be that the thread has stalled (e.g. deadlocked) or entered an infinite loop.